# A Chain of Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ Without any Good Countable Subchain

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Consider which $\bigl{(} A_i \bigr{)}_{i\in I}$ is a [chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order#Chains) of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. 
We say that a countable chain like $\bigl{(} B_n \bigr{)}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is good if :

- for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the set $B_n$ be an element of the main chain $\bigl{(} A_i \bigr{)}_{i\in I}$
- for every $i\in I$ there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $A_i \subset B_n $.

Give an example of $\bigl{(} A_i \bigr{)}_{i\in I}$ which for it, does not exist such a good chain $\bigl{(} B_n \bigr{)}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$.

Such an example surely exists and surely exists of subsets with lebesgue zero measure, because if there does not exist then we can find a maximal zero measure set by using Zorn's lemma.

Comment: It seems to me that it should be possible if you can write $\mathbb R$ as a disjoint union of uncountably many uncountable sets.  So can we write $\mathbb R$ as a disjoint union of uncountably many uncountable sets?

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, $\mathbb R\cong \mathbb R^2$. - But I donÄt see how that helps.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good point.  And $\Bbb R^2$ clearly admits a chain that has no good chain.  To be explicit about it though, one would need an explicit bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Gregory: What is the chain?

Comment: @AsafKaragila You mean in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant An explici *injection* of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$ is easy and should then suffice as well.

Comment: @Gregory: Yeah.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Do you happen to know that it is impossible?

Comment: @Gregory: That what is impossible? I gave an answer saying that it is possible. Noah gave a similar answer. It is possible, it's just not trivial without some set theoretic knowledge, and discarding much of the "natural" structure of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What you are asking me to do.

Comment: @Gregory: I don't know what you had in mind. So I'm trying to see where you're going with it before I can tell you how and where your idea fails, or if it does indeed work out.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Zorn's lemma. Okay, almost nothing to do with Zorn.

Essentially we say that a chain $\mathcal A$ is good, if there is a countable subchain which is cofinal in $\mathcal A$.

So all you need is to show there is a chain which is not of countable cofinality.

For example $\aleph_1$ is regular, assuming "enough choice", and there is always a chain $(A_i)_{i<\omega_1}$, such a chain cannot be good if $\aleph_1$ is regular.

I don't see a natural approach to this using Zorn's lemma as a means for construction such a chain.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasonably simple such chains, all revolving around the same idea: that the first uncountable ordinal, $\omega_1$, is *regular*, that is, cannot be written as a countable union of countable ordinals.

Here's one natural class of examples: for $\eta<\omega_1$, let $A_\eta$ be the set of all reals which code well-orderings of $\omega$ of order type $<\eta$, or which do not code well-orderings of $\omega$ at all. Then clearly $A_\eta\subsetneq A_\theta$ whenever $\eta<\theta$, so we have a chain, but since $\omega_1$ is regular, there can be no good countable subchain. The specific example depends on the choice of "coding apparatus" for representing binary relations on $\omega$ as real numbers.

Another natural class: Via Zorn, let $\mathcal{C}=\{d_\eta: \eta<\omega_1\}$ be a a strictly increasing chain of Turing degrees. Then for each $\eta$ let $A_\eta=\{X: X\not\ge_T d_\eta\}.$ The specific example produced depends on the choice of the chain $\mathcal{C}$.

There is a serious difference between these two examples, even though they are similar in flavor: there are explicit coding methods, and hence nicely definable instances of the first type. However, it is consistent that there is no "nicely definable" chain $\mathcal{C}$ of $\omega_1$-many Turing degrees, so the latter class of examples is meaningfully less constructive than the former.

---

Note that I needed to assume that $\omega_1$ is regular, in both parts. I believe this is necessary - that is, that it is consistent with ZF that every chain has a good countable subchain - but I can't prove it; I suspect Gitik's model provides an example, though.

Comment: Well... you know... assuming choice. :-)

Comment: What does "code" mean here? View the binary digits of $x\in\mathbb R$ as a relation $\subseteq\omega\times\omega$ ?

Comment: @Hagen: If you think about a real number as a sequence of integers, then you can think about it as a sequence of ordered pairs of integers, and you can ask if this sequence of ordered pairs is in fact a relation which is a well-ordering of its domain. Then if the answer is positive, you can ask what is its order type?

Comment: Noah, I wanted to say something about Gitik's model, but I have my doubts. I think that you need the stronger and-yet-to-be-proved-consistent principle $\sf (K)$ which asserts, essentially, that every set is the countable union of smaller sets. This might not be enough as it is, since it might be the case that you have a chain which is the countable union of smaller chains, but you might not be able to choose a cofinal sequence using that decomposition. So the real question is whether or not it is consistent that every linear order has countable cofinality or a maximum. I don't know the answer

Comment: Well, but we're only talking about chains of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ - do we still need $(K)$?

Comment: Noah, probably not. We can probably get with a very limited version of $\sf (K)$, namely that $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$ is the countable union of countable union ... of countable sets. This ensures that every chain has a countable decomposition, but it still does not ensure that every chain is good since we would need to choose from these chains and that just might be impossible. It's very unclear to me.

Comment: (The limited form itself will probably require some very large cardinals, by the way, since it seems to me provable that the least uncountable regular cardinal is at least $\aleph_3$, so we get to the vicinity of Woodin and above.)

Comment: So having thought about it some more, here's a weaker question: does every *well-orderable* chain of sets have a good subchain? The answer is affirmative if $\Theta$ has countable cofinality, which I believe it does in Gitik's model; thoughts?

Comment: Well, in Gitik's model you have that every nonempty well ordered set has a maximum or countable cofinality. And indeed you only need that all the ordinals that can be order embedded into $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Hmm, after some reflections Gitik's model could probably serve as a counterexample, if one does indeed exists. I think that we're overextending the comments here. If you want to discuss about this further, I'd be most happy to do so over email. :-)